# Can I make Eclipse pick up my C++ Code Style without any manual steps?

Tags: c++, eclipse, configuration

I am trying to set a custom C++ Code Style profile in Eclipse from an external tool. I have found that this is set in the file:

`...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs`

and I have managed to add my Code Style profile there.

When I start Eclipse my profile is selected as the active one under `Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style` but still it is not working when I try to do something in the editor. I have to go into the preferences and choose `Edit... -> OK` on my profile for it to be picked up by Eclipse.

Is there any way I can make Eclipse automatically use my profile on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one more file where the Code Style profile has to be present:

`...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.cdt.core.prefs`

Once this is in place the profile will be active and working on Eclipse startup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In same file look at `formatter_profile` option.

For example:

```
formatter_profile=_Torsten
```

Also, seems `_` - underscore required before name.

Comment: I have set this option to my profile already. This is why it shows up as the active one in Eclipse preferences. But the problem is that even though it is shown as the active one, it is not really active.

Comment: You doing something wrong or have broken eclipse. I've checked changing profile directly from configuration file and it's work as expected. Indigo SR 2.

Comment: I will try in another version and see if it works better. Thanks.